# PDO suspected of escaping characters of my Blob in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, base64, blob

### Context

I store image in BLOBs columns in a MySql DB with PDO (*yeah, this is needed*).

I upload a `base64_encoded` .png from client's browser to a .php webservice through AJAX, and store it on my data base using `base64_decode()`.

Later, I get it back on the client's browser. And upload it again, and so on until space-time continuum breaks.

**Retrieving** a valid BLOB (imported directly on phpMyAdmin, so 100% sure) from the database is fine, I can print it well on browser.

But **storing it** on MySql...

---

### Issue

Setting looks like that :

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Me', 'My', 'Myself');   
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); //I tried playing with charset too

$query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE i_like_underscores SET `my_blob`=:my_blob WHERE `it`=`:belongs");

$my_blob = base64_decode($_POST['my_blob']);
$query->bindParam(':my_blob', $my_blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
//The WHERE clause has really no importance here, so I don't even bind it
$query->execute();
```

It seems that **PDO systematically removes some special characters** of my blob during this process (but I can't diagnostic when exactly), cause when I later get my picture back (and encode it on base64), **all the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> are gone from my base64 string** (while <kbd>/</kbd> stills) === corrupted.

I guess it automatically escapes when I bind it, but I can't tell as `base64_decoded` .png data is encoded in a unreadable weird charset.

I spent many hours on it, and tried :

- Changing the encoding
- `PDO::quote()` after base64_decode()
- Putting various quotes on my SQL query
- Prepared statements and direct `PDO::query`
- Surfing the web for docs on all the PDO function I used
- Finding similar cases, on StackOverflow too, no luck
- To see how it's done in phpMyAdmin
- Setting type `PDO::PARAM_STR`
- Not thinking about quitting PDO just for that special case
- Writing all my code backwards
- And black magic

Without luck... Could someone give me a clue?

Comment: PDO will not add or remove characters on you. That'd defeat the purpose of using placeholders. You should also not need to base64 encode the data before stuffing it into the DB. base64 causes a ~33% size increase in the data, and the db is perfectly capable of storing arbitrary binary data using a `blob`-type field.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not storing base64 encoded data in my DB; I decode it from my client's JSON and then try to store it.

Comment: right. my bad. then definitely check that you're getting out of base64_decode there is what it SHOULD be. e.g. does that data, without involving the DB at all, still work as a png image? If not, then you'll have to figure out why it's getting to your server corrupted.

Comment: Have you disabled [**emulation**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) of prepared statements? ie `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );`

Comment: @davidstrachan Thank you! Now, the `=` character is conserved, but the `+` is still missing (I have no idea why the `=<` is kept now)! Any idea?

Comment: @Bigood I personally don't like storing images as blobs and store them in the file system with the path/URL in database. I don't have any idea what is causing your new problem.

Comment: @davidstrachan Thanks for your time... I'll find another way then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to davidstrachan, I've solved the removal of <kbd>=</kbd> using :

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Then, I came back to that problem later, just to see that the serialization of my form in jQuery was done wrong.

It escaped all the <kbd>+</kbd> as spaces (or `%20`) instead of `%2B`.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain? Am I wrong to publicly admit I made a mistake, and this is not only a PDO issue?